# method wont pull correct data from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

So basically whats happened is my code compiles and runs fine. but when it runs the value stored for the minScore and minName variables stay 0

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   int count = 0;
   string[] names = new string[MAX_SIZE];
   int[] scores = new int[MAX_SIZE];

   string name;
   int sum = 0;
   int minScore = 0;
   int maxScore = 0;
   string minName = string.Empty;
   string maxName = string.Empty;
   string input;
   int score;

   Console.WriteLine("===============Saturday Night Coders================");
   Console.WriteLine("===============Bowling Score Program================");

   for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("\n Please Enter a name and a score separated by a space");
      Console.WriteLine("Enter a blank line when finished");

      input = Console.ReadLine();

      if (input == "")
      {
         count = i;
         Console.WriteLine("===========INPUT COMPLETE=========");
         break;
      }

      string[] splitInput = input.Split();

      name = splitInput[0];
      score = int.Parse(splitInput[1]);
      scores[i] = score;
      names[i] = name;
      sum += score;
      if (minScore >= score)
      {
         minScore = score;
         minName = name;
      }

      if (maxScore <= score)
      {
         maxScore = score;
         maxName = name;
      }
      count = i + 1;
    }

      double average = sum / count;
      Console.WriteLine("Here are the scores for this game");
      PrintScores(names, scores, count);
      Console.WriteLine("Congratulations {0}, your score of {1} was the highest",maxName, maxScore);
      Console.WriteLine("{0} , your score of {1} was the lowest, Maybe you should find a new hobby",minName, minScore);
      Console.WriteLine("\n The team average was {0:f2}", average);
      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void PrintScores(string[] names, int[] scores, int count)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0} \t {1}", names[i], scores[i]);
            if (scores[i] == MAX_SCORE)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why the for loop works for the maxName and maxScore statement, but not the minName and minScore statements. any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this code:

```
 int minScore = 0;
 int maxScore = 0;
```

Its a much better practice to use

```
 int minScore = int.MaxValue;
 int maxScore = int.MinValue;
```

So any value is smaller than initial minvalue, and any value is greater than initial max value.

Comment: Thank you so much that completely fixed the issue. and as for good practice, I'll make sure I do that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may have made a logical error in setting the default `minScore` to 0.
If this is the case 0 will never be higher or equal to any score above 0:

```
if (minScore >= score)
```

is actually

```
if (0 >= score)
```

Try the following instead:

```
if (minScore == 0 || minScore >= score)
```

Comment: Although you may need to factor in additional code or use a different default value for `minScore` if you can have a minimum score of 0.